# Find rows in which the total of certain cells in that row does not equal 5

Tags: excel, google-sheets, numbers

So I am getting data fed into a spreadsheet on Google Sheets. I cannot edit that spreadsheet.

I have an additional sheet in the document that totals up the columns in this sheet. The sheet received info such as:

```
  A  B  C  D        This info is not actually in the sheet
|------------|        \/    \/
| 4  1  0  0 |      <-- Valid
| 3  1  1  0 |      <-- Valid
| 3  1  0  2 |      <-- Invalid
| 3  0  1  1 |      <-- Valid
|------------|
```

The total of each individual row should be 5, but I do not currently have a way of validating this in the form itself. So I need to disregard or remove the data if it is in violation.

Basically, I want to find the first row in which the total of these 4 cells are not 5.

Comment: So is this an additional question than the [LAST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991604/only-add-cells-in-column-when-the-total-of-multiple-other-cells-in-that-row-equa/35991740#35991740) or did you ask the wrong question the last time?

Comment: Would conditional formatting work to show you your rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only add cells in column when the total of multiple other cells in that row equals 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991604/only-add-cells-in-column-when-the-total-of-multiple-other-cells-in-that-row-equa)

Answer (score 1):

In excel try this Array formula:

```
=MATCH(1,IF(($A$1:$A$4+$B$1:$B$4+$C$1:$C$4+$D$1:$D$4)<>5,1,0),0)
```

This needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

In google sheets it would simply be:

```
=ArrayFormula(MATCH(1,IF(($A$1:$A$4+$B$1:$B$4+$C$1:$C$4+$D$1:$D$4)<>5,1,0),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Clever. I like the array in the middle (if that's the right term).  I wish you could just use `A1:D4`, entered as array but I guess you can't...